# do en Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Estoy creando un guard para Angular 6 y me he encontrado con el problema de que los operadores `rxjs` ya no van como antes. A parte de imortarse de manera distinta, he tenido que meter el `.map` o `.task` dentro de un `.pipe()`. Esto me ha permitido solventar los problemas. Sin embargo, no veo como sustituir o importar el operador `.do`.

Os muestro mi código y a ver si me podéis ayudar a encontrar una alternativa. El error que me da VSC es:

> "El módulo '"c:/Users/subir/Desktop/GiramosCPanel/node_modules/rxjs/operators/index"' no tiene ningún miembro 'do' exportado."  y  "La propiedad 'do' no existe en el tipo 'Observable'.".

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { map, take, do } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor (
private router: Router,
private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.authService.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    take(1)).pipe(
    map(authState => !! authState)).do(logado => {
      if (!logado) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir de la versión 6 de *rxjs*, hubo grandes cambios ahí el porque de tu problema.

Varios operadores cambiaron de nombre, porque coincidían con los de *JavaScript*, como por ejemplo:

- `do => tap`
- `catch => catchError`
- `switch => switchAll`
- `finally => finalize`

Otro punto importante es que no puedes encadenar operadores como se hacia anteriormente, debes usar `.pipe()`

*Código Ejemplo:*

```
// Antes de la V6
source
 .map(x => x + x)
 .mergeMap(n => of(n + 1, n + 2)
   .filter(x => x % 1 == 0)
   .scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
 )
 .catch(err => of('error found'))
 .subscribe(printResult);

 // Ahora en la V6 se debe hacer de la siguiente forma
 source.pipe(
 map(x => x + x),
 mergeMap(n => of(n + 1, n + 2).pipe(
   filter(x => x % 1 == 0),
   scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0),
 )),
 catchError(err => of('error found')),
).subscribe(printResult);
```

---

Alternativa:

> Si tienes otro proyecto viejo podrías seguir usando la forma anterior
>   instalando el siguiente modulo de compatibilidad, **lo cual no es
>   recomendado ya que es preferible que actualices tu código**:
>
> `npm install rxjs-compat@6 --save`

---

Fuente: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration

Comment: Hola Federico! Genial tu respuesta. Funciona sustituyendo el do por tap y metiendolo dentro de un .pipe(). Gracias. :)